# Eclipse Jdk issue while building the project

Tags: java, eclipse, java-7, java-6

I have been working in eclipse project environment from 6 month. but due to change in the jdk version as per project requirement, i shifted from the jdk 1.6 to jdk 1.7.0_25. now i am getting an issue of 
        `An error occured while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.jdt.debug.ui(347).`Even i tried to add the jdk in the preference -> java -> installed jre. Here i am getting an error of `An error has occured when creating this preference page`. My eclipse is 32 bit and jdk is also 32 bit

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory for more details of the errors.

Comment: while looking into the .log file there are lot of failure scenarios

Comment: Close Eclipse, delete the `.log`, then restart Eclipse and reproduce the problem. At that point the `.log` should be more usable.